# transforming numeric values to POSIXct

Tags: merge, posixct

I'm having a problem transforming my numeric values to POSIXct after I'd merged two data frames together. I had some variated data and wanted to make periods of one day. It worked fine, so until now I have a data frame with time stamps of one day and where there are no values for certain days, it says NA. That's what I wanted. But with the transformation and for the merge, my date (POSIXct) values had to be transformed to numeric. Now I want to transform them back to POSIXct values so I can see the dates in the x axis after making a plot.

So basically my question is: how can I transform the numeric values to POSIXct?

This is the script I made to transform the data into a univariate data. NL1per is my irregular data that contains POSIXct values for dates, NL1list is the data frame where the dates are ordered per day and numeric. It's the column "Period" of that particular data frame I want to transform after merging.

```
NL1per=NL1r
NL1per$Datum...tijd = as.POSIXct(NL1per$Datum...tijd,format="%b-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="GMT")
NL1per$Period=as.numeric(NL1per$Datum...tijd) %/% 3600 * 3600
Date=as.numeric(trunc(NL1per$Datum...tijd,"day"))
nNL1per=data.frame(Period=seq(min(Date),max(Date)+86399,by=3600))
nNL1per= merge(NL1per[c('Incl.X.mm.m','Incl.Y.mm.m','Period')],nNL1per,by="Period",all=T)
NL1list=aggregate(cbind(nNL1per$Incl.X.mm.m,nNL1per$Incl.Y.mm.m),list(Period=nNL1per$Period),mean)
```

Comment: You really should edit your post. That big chunck of raw data does not really add anything.

Comment: I just found out how to let it work. For anyone who has the same question: NL1list$Period = structure(NL1list$Period,class=c('POSIXt','POSIXct'))